# Seeing figures inside a tex/latex buffer in emacs

Tags: graphics, emacs

Quite often while typing in emacs I will LaTeX a file just to see whether I am including the right figures in the right order. Is there an emacs package that will either:

- show the figure within the latex source file
  or
- show the figure when the mouse hovers over an `\includegraphics` command?

The idea is to truly ignore the typesetting while one is typing and to delay the latex iterations as long as possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Some text...

\includegraphics{figure.pdf}

Some more text...

\end{document}
```

In the example above, I'd like emacs to show me the content of 'figure.pdf' whenever I hover over `\includegraphics`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248638/seeing-figures-inside-a-tex-latex-buffer-in-emacs?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is far from a satisfactory answer, but probably too long for a comment.

You might want to read the docs for `preview-latex`, particularly chapter 4 "Simple customization", section "Preview your favourite LaTeX constructs".  (Notice: I did not actually check it, and I don't know enough about dvipng to be sure that this would work.)  If it works, it does in a weird way: it would typeset a small LaTeX document, bascially with only your \includegraphic command, convert the resulting dvi to png, and put it there.  This means that it most probably won't work for jpg/pdf files (and if it will, then only for jpg and if you give the bounding box manually), but might work for eps files.  (And this would require typing some keychord instead of hovering your mouse, probably.)

Another idea would be to look into `preview-latex` source and try to do something similar for jpgs/pdfs.  Notice that you'd have to take care of the size of bitmaps; I would imagine using `convert` to, well, convert them to some reasonable size.

Comment: I'm studying your suggestion and will report back shortly, but in the meantime I have a comment regarding migrating questions... Are you also surprised that this question has everything to do with emacs and much less to do with latex in particular? I wish the point collectors would at least ask in which venue the OP would like to post.

Comment: Well, I am indeed, but notice that there are probably more TeX users here than on stackoverflow.org.  (Personally, I'd ask this on some emacs mailing list anyway.)